# How can I setup an IDE in Vagrant? Is this a good idea?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm totally new to vagrant and wanted to ask if it is possible to setup my development enviroment (Java; Netbeans; Ant; maybe link to Subversion) in Vagrant.

The idea would be to have a 'clean'/same configuration IDE with all the same versions for each development project.

Or am I missing the point of Vagrant? And it should work like a build-server?
Is there any point besides simulating a component for testing (like a server or production enviroment?)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can install your whole development environment within a vagrant VM. It does not matter if you use it as reproducible and independent development or test environment.

For more information see the 'Why Vagrant Section' on the developer home page
http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/why-vagrant/index.html

Comment: I found different articles that claim, that vagrant has a slow response time in the IDE:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625421/vagrant-for-a-java-project-should-you-compile-in-the-vm-or-on-the-host

Or is this not the case anymore?

Comment: That heavily depends on the performance of your host machine. Many of my collegues develop within a VM and they are happy with it. It showed that a SSD speeds up things noticeably. It would give it a try.